# Issue with Zend framework controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am a newbie to the Zend framework.

I am getting an error while loading my index controller:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Places' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\zend\book\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 36
```

My bootstrapper code is

```
<?php
class Bootstrap
{
    public function __construct($configSection)
    {
        $rootDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
        define('ROOT_DIR', $rootDir);
        set_include_path(get_include_path(). PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR . '/library/'. PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT_DIR .
        '/application/models/');

        require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
        $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        // Load configuration
        Zend_Registry::set('configSection',$configSection);
        $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(ROOT_DIR.'/application/config.ini',$configSection);
        Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
        date_default_timezone_set($config->date_default_timezone);
        // configure database and store to the registry
        $db = Zend_Db::factory($config->db);
        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
        Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);
    }

    public function configureFrontController()
    {
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $frontController->setControllerDirectory(ROOT_DIR .'/application/controllers');
    }

    public function runApp()
    {
        $this->configureFrontController();
        // run!
        $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $frontController->dispatch();
    }
}
```

I have a model:

```
<?php
class Places extends Zend_Db_Table
{
    protected $_name = 'places'; //table name
    function fetchLatest($count = 10)
    {
        return $this->fetchAll(null,'date_created DESC', $count);
    }   
}
```

My index controller code is:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->title = 'Welcome';
        $placesFinder = new Places();
        $this->view->places = $places->fetchLatest();
    }
}
```

I am using ZF version 1.10.4

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance you are missing somethign in your class declaration
try:

```
   <?php
class Models_Places extends Zend_Db_Table
{
    protected $_name = 'places'; //table name
    function fetchLatest($count = 10)
    {
        return $this->fetchAll(null,'date_created DESC', $count);
    }   
}
```

The Zend autoloader class will look into Models/places.php for your class.

Also you could initialise the models and default module in bootstrap with:

```
protected function _initAutoload() {

        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                    'namespace' => '',
                    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__),
                ));
        $autoloader->addResourceType('models', 'models/', 'Models');
        return $autoloader;
    }
```

After having done that your class should be named Models_Places.

Check out the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html) about autoloading.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it doesn't  seems to be working with your code

Comment: Well what is not working? It should work unless you have a problem somewhere in your code.

Comment: showing same error, I think there is something missing on the $loader ?

Comment: I could solve this issue by adding include('Places.php'); at the top of the IndexController, Is there anyway to avoid this inclusion,I would like to load it automatically

Comment: Read what I linked about the autoloader. Normaly if you initialise it in bootstrap like I showed it should work unless your folders are organised differently.

Answer (score 0):

Well, personally, I use extended controllers which contain few util methods I use very often. Here is a snippet of my extended controller:

```
<?php
class My_MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $_tables = array();

    protected function _getTable($table)
    {
        if (false === array_key_exists($table, $this->_tables)) {
            include APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/'
            . $this->_request->getModuleName() . '/models/' . $table . '.php';
            $this->_tables[$table] = new $table();
        }
        return $this->_tables[$table];
    }
}
```

You just need to define the APPLICATION_PATH in index.php. Then your controller could look like this:

```
<?php
class IndexController extends My_MyController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // get model
        $model = $this->_getTable('ModelName');
    }
}
```

Path where you store the My_Controller must also be in your include path.